# New line for sublime-completion file trigger?

Tags: sublimetext3, code-snippets

I'm writing a small set of snippets for when I do WebGL as the library is quite massive and it's annoying having to always consult the documentation. I have the following:

```
{
   "scope": "text.html",

   "completions":
   [
      { 
        "trigger": "DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT\tIndicates the depth buffer", 
        "contents": "DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT"
      },

      { 
        "trigger": "STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT\tIndicates the stencil buffer", 
        "contents": "STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT" 
      },

      { 
        "trigger": "COLOR_BUFFER_BIT\tIndicates the buffers currently enabled for color writing", 
        "contents": "COLOR_BUFFER_BIT" 
      }
   ]
}
```

Obviously the COLOR_BUFFER_BIT section is a bit long, and on the popup for the snippet the line covers most of my screen, I was wondering if there was a way to force a new line, because I know in the future I'm going to be adding ones with fairly long descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. Snippets, `.sublime-completion` files, and other methods of populating the completions popup only have one line per completion suggestion, otherwise scrolling through it with the arrow keys would lead to ambiguous behavior. I'm sure you can pare down the descriptions you already have - for example, get rid of "Indicates the" for all three, and the last one could be shortened to "enabled color writing buffer" or something like that.

Comment: I see....I wonder if then there is a way to load a description somewhere on the screen, like a small box to the side or something, because for smaller ones like that it may be perfectly acceptable to shorten it but for more complex functions and things like that it would be very useful to be able to have a good explanation of what the function does (I'm thinking in terms of distributing this as a learning resource). Do you know of anything like that? This is similar to what I'm talking about:

https://aspblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/jalpeshpvadgama/Media/Intellisense_4E64E2E9.png

Comment: @TrevorHart Sublime Text 3 now has the [tooltip API](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3070/14538). [Google around](https://www.google.com/#q=sublime+tooltip+api) for examples of plugins already using it.